# How to Develop Insight - Samathayanika

Tags: meditation-insight

If I practice tranquility meditation how would I go about developing insight.How does a samathayanika realise Nibbanna.

Comment: So in other words, are you asking "How is insight developed in tranquility-based traditions?"

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 6):

As per the Visuddhimagga:

> Herein, “purification of view” is the correct seeing of mentality-materiality.
>
> One who wants to accomplish this, if, firstly, his vehicle is serenity, should
>   emerge from any fine-material or immaterial jhāna, except the base consisting of
>   neither perception nor non-perception, and he should discern, according to
>   characteristic, function, etc., the jhāna factors consisting of applied thought,
>   etc., and the states associated with them, [that is, feeling, perception, and so on].
>
> When he has done so, all that should be defined as “mentality” (nāma) in the
>   sense of bending (namana) because of its bending on to the object.
>
> Then, just as a man, by following a snake that he has seen in his house, finds
>   its abode, so too this meditator scrutinizes that mentality, he seeks to find out
>   what its occurrence is supported by and he sees that it is supported [588] by the
>   matter of the heart. After that, he discerns as materiality the primary elements,
>   which are the heart’s support, and the remaining, derived kinds of materiality
>   that have the elements as their support. He defines all that as “materiality” (rūpa) because it is “molested” (ruppana) [by cold, etc.]. After that he defines in brief as “mentality-materiality” (nāma-rūpa) the mentality that has the characteristic of “bending” and the materiality that has the characteristic of “being molested.”
>
> Path of Purification, XVIII 2-4

Basically, it entails using the jhana factors and their physical support as a basis for insight - seeing them as impermanent, suffering, and non-self to the point of realizing the four noble truths.